# Kernel Header 3.14.32-xxxx-std-ipv6-64

Tags: drivers, kernel

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Cloud system base system. I have installed VMware Workstation 12 & VirtualBox 5.1 on base system. After launching the application, VMware Workstation getting an error `Kernel Header 3.14.32-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 could not found`. I have tried to install kernel-header for the same but again getting another error `Couldn't find any package by regex linux-header-3.14.32-xxxx-std-ipv6-64`

Same problem getting while starting application VirtualBox Manager. While starting VM getting error

> ```
> Kernel driver not installed (rc=1908)
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv
> ```

I have entered below command `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(unamge -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms`

Comment: I don't see any screenshots.

Comment: And you mispelled `uname -r` as  **WRONG** `umange -r` **WRONG**

Comment: The kernel you are using is not an official Ubuntu one. Ask whoever provided this kernel about how to obtain the headers.